# Bug while trying to award a bounty

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounty

I'm getting the following message on the console when I try to [award a bounty on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26029936/340760)

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
>
> full.en.js?v=736ee3eb3231:4

The first time I click I can see the popup, then I click OK and it crashes with the above message. Then I try to click again and the popup doesn't even work anymore.

Comment: What browser (name, version, OS, any enabled extensions)?  Have you tried more than one?  Sometimes logging out of your SO profile and back in can clear corrupted cookies and get things working again.

Comment: (This is on the hot questions list right now.) Upvoters, what's the matter? Are you reproducing the problem?

Comment: I suspect upvoters think the problem is important.

Comment: @Athari yes because with a bounty bug your reputation you invested is at risk.

Comment: The [mutex](http://stackoverflow.com/users/385024/mutex) is probably locked, you have to wait.

Comment: I'm currently unable to award a bounty today. 23 hours until it automatically goes to the wrong people! :-(

Comment: I had the same problem but reported this on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240267/cant-award-bounty-js-error-on-page-around-vote-sub . It seems important if we could find out if this bug exists only on SO or on every SE site. If anybody knows a similar problem on other SE sites, please let us know.

Comment: @Peter too bad we need to wait for so much time before being able to award a bounty, otherwise I could test it now. (spending half association bonus on a random site is no big deal :))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry about that. Fixed now; you can award the bounty.